# How to add variable,function,class which defined in run time to CodeMirror auto completion list and remove them when deleting from code in JS

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

I'm using [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) library for my online python code editor project.It's auto completion working fine. But  I want to add user defined variables, functions, classes to auto complete list and remove them from list when I remove the definition from editor at run time. Also I want to do this in vanilla JS without JQuery.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
        mode: {
            name: "python",
            version: 3,
            singleLineStringErrors: false
        },
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        extraKeys: {
            "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete",
            "Ctrl-/": "toggleComment",
            "Alt-E": runCode,
            "Alt-C": clearOutput

        },
        matchBrackets: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true
    });
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 Sorry. I have updated the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that anyword-hint.js of CodeMirror can use to acomplish this task.
So I combine the functionality of [python-hint.js](https://github.com/mvickymca/codemirror_python_autocomplete/blob/master/addon/hint/python-hint.js) & anyword-hint.js.
(I used npm to install CodeMirror because I was working with a NodeJs project)

```
<script src="node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/codemirror/mode/python/python.js"></script>

<script src="python-hint.js"></script>
<!-- this script not contains in CodeMirror. I have added manually -->


<script src="node_modules/codemirror/addon/hint/anyword-hint.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css">

 <script>
    function getAllHints(e) {
        var hints = CodeMirror.pythonHint(e);
        var anyHints = CodeMirror.hint.anyword(e);

        anyHints.list.forEach(function(hint) {
            if (hints.list.indexOf(hint) == -1)
                hints.list.push(hint);
        })

        hints.list.sort();

        if (hints) {
            CodeMirror.on(hints, "pick", function(word) {
                if (word.charAt(word.length - 1) == ')')
                    editor.execCommand("goCharLeft");
            });
        }
        return hints;
    }

    function showAllHints() {
        editor.showHint({
            hint: getAllHints,
            completeSingle: false
        });
    }

    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
        mode: {
            name: "python",
            version: 3
        },
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4
    });

    editor.on('inputRead', function onChange(editor, input) {
        if (input.text[0] === ' ' || input.text[0] === ":" || input.text[0] === ")") {
            return;
        }
        showAllHints();
    });
</script>
```

I have removed

```
if(completionList.length == 1) {
  completionList.push(" ");
}
```

(35-37 lines) from [python-hint.js](https://github.com/mvickymca/codemirror_python_autocomplete/blob/master/addon/hint/python-hint.js) because I have set `completeSingle: false` in my `showAllHints()` function.

I know that `getAllHints(e)` function can optimize more & have some issues like can't filter out variable, function, class names. 
Which means the hint list includes variable, function, class names & also includes previously typed strings, numbers etc.
However this is what I expected to do. So I decided to post as a answer before optimizing. 
Any optimization tips, suggestions an more better answers also welcome.